How to bring one result from a table searching for multiples columns from another tables
Sup. Noob dev here.
I have one table that stores ITEMS and another with PRICES.
Prices one is multiple rows per item, if someone updates the price it appends the table with another row with the date that the price will be valid. So if I need to know the current price I have to look for the max(date) where date<=now().
The problem is, I need to build a view to integrate an API with the last price, and can't figure out a way to do it efficiently because every way I try the query takes 1~2 min to result (we are talking about 250k items and a lot of history prices)

I've already tried a lateral join:

SELECT i.item,
    i.unidade,
    l.empresa,
    l.valor,
    l.dtvalida
 FROM itens i
JOIN LATERAL ( 
     SELECT t.empresa,
            t.tabela,
            t.tipo,
            t.codigo,
            t.unidade,
            t.dtvalida,
            t.valor,
            t.valormin
      FROM tpreco t
 LEFT JOIN paemp pa ON t.empresa = pa.empresa
     WHERE t.codigo = i.item AND t.tabela::text = pa.fattabavis::text
       AND t.empresa = 1265 AND t.unidade::text = i.unidade::text
       AND t.dtvalida <=now()
          ORDER BY t.dtvalida DESC
     LIMIT 1) l ON true

This does a good job showing results when I have low number of items, once I scale it takes very long.

Tried a very junky way

select i.item, 
       i.descricao, 
       i.unidade,  
       ei.empresa,  
       t1.valor,  
       t1.dtvalida  
  From itens i
left join empitens ei on ei.item = i.item and (ei.precocodificado<>'S')
left join paemp p on p.empresa = ei.empresa
join tpreco t1 on t1.codigo = i.item 
              and t1.empresa = ei.empresa 
              and t1.tabela = p.fattabavis
              and t1.unidade = i.unidade
              and t1.dtvalida = (
                     select max(t2.dtvalida) 
                       from tpreco t2 
                      where t2.codigo = t1.codigo 
                        and t2.empresa = t1.empresa
                        and t2.tabela = t1.tabela
                            and t2.unidade = t1.unidade
                                            )

Same problem, surprisingly this works very well on low items count, but high not.
And tried a function to calculate this price, but when I call it in the other view (where I originally use the current price) it also took too long
create function ult_preco_f(_emp bigint, _tab varchar, _item bigint, _un varchar)
returns float
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
   last_valor float;
begin
   select valor
   into max_valor
   from tpreco
   where empresa = _emp
     and tabela = _tab
     and codigo = _item
     and unidade = _un
     and dtvalida<=now()
order by dtvalida desc
limit 1;

   return last_valor;
end;
$$;

Ty to anyone willing to help.

As idea, find latest price with row_number().
Try
SELECT i.item,
    i.unidade,
    l.empresa,
    l.valor,
    l.dtvalida
 FROM itens i
 inner JOIN ( 
     SELECT t.empresa,
            t.tabela,
            t.tipo,
            t.codigo,
            t.unidade,
            t.dtvalida,
            t.valor,
            t.valormin,
          row_numbser()over(partition by t.codigo,t.unidade
                             order by t.dtvalida DESC)rn
     FROM tpreco t
     LEFT JOIN paemp pa ON t.empresa = pa.empresa
     WHERE  t.tabela::text = pa.fattabavis::text
       AND t.empresa = 1265 
       AND t.dtvalida <=now()
     ) l ON l.codigo = i.item AND t.unidade::text = i.unidade::text
      and l.rn=1

OR
Possible join paemp after calculation of last price. Then search for last price simplified and may be, faster with proper index on tpreco table.
SELECT i.item,
    i.unidade,
    l.empresa,
    l.valor,
    l.dtvalida
 FROM itens i
 inner JOIN ( 
     SELECT t.empresa,
            t.tabela,
            t.tipo,
            t.codigo,
            t.unidade,
            t.dtvalida,
            t.valor,
            t.valormin,
          row_numbser()over(partition by t.codigo,t.unidade
                             order by t.dtvalida DESC)rn
     FROM tpreco t
       AND t.empresa = 1265 
       AND t.dtvalida <=now()
     ) l ON l.codigo = i.item AND t.unidade::text = i.unidade::text
      and l.rn=1
   LEFT JOIN paemp pa ON l.empresa = pa.empresa
     and  l.tabela::text = pa.fattabavis::text


I don't know table structure and links. Thats an idea only.

Thanks for this answer, the first iteration shaves one whole minute from the query. Now I'm sitting on 2 seconds query, which is very acceptable for this operation.

You should use group by clause.
Assuming that tpreco.dtvalida is a date of processing order and tpreco.codigo is the item code, so the last order would be the following query
select codigo, max(dtvalida) dtvalida from tpreco group by codigo;

Then you can join these rows with original table to get the other values of the same rows using INNER JOIN.
SELECT t.empresa
     , t.tabela
     , t.tipo
     , t.codigo
     , t.dtvalida
     , t.valor
     , t.valormin
  FROM tpreco t
INNER JOIN (select codigo, max(dtvalida) dtvalida from tpreco group by codigo) m 
   ON t.codigo = m.codigo AND t.dtvalida = m.dtvalida;

And finally you can join this with your table itens.
SELECT i.item
     , i.unidade
     , l.empresa
     , l.valor
     , l.dtvalida
  FROM itens i
INNER JOIN (
SELECT t.empresa
     , t.tabela
     , t.tipo
     , t.codigo
     , t.dtvalida
     , t.valor
     , t.valormin
  FROM tpreco t
INNER JOIN (select codigo, max(dtvalida) dtvalida from tpreco group by codigo) m 
   ON t.codigo = m.codigo AND t.dtvalida = m.dtvalida
LEFT JOIN paemp pa ON t.empresa = pa.empresa
 WHERE t.tabela::text = pa.fattabavis::text
   AND t.empresa = 1265 AND t.unidade::text = i.unidade::text
   AND t.dtvalida <= now()
) l ON i.item = l.codigo;

I think you can also use another aggregate function (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html) with order by, but that was the best solution I could think.

Probably with some testing you could pick the best results, but here is my take. Many tries before shown that you should always try to avoid subquerys and data operations out of a SELECT clause, so you could try with some Common Table Expressions:
With tPreco_CTE AS (
   SELECT 
       tpreco.empresa,
       MAX(tpreco.valor)
   FROM tpreco
   WHERE tpreco.empresa = $SomeConstant
       AND tpreco.codigo = $AnotherConstant
)
SELECT 
    itens.unidade,
    tPrecos_CTE.empresa,
FROM itens
INNER JOIN tPreco_CTE ON tPreco_CTE.empresa = itens.empresa
-- And so on... 

Just include your other columns there and you'll be fine.
Boa sorte!
